# Adding dynamic custom styles with priority not working in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to develop a Wordpress theme and I am trying to add Options in my Theme to customize the default style. For this I have added a function that get user defined values and insert defined styles in head section using `wp_enqueue_scripts()`

```
 function woo_wonder_custom_style(){

     $custom_background_color = get_option('ww_background_color');

 ?>

    <style type="text/css">
        body{
             background-color: <?php echo $custom_background_color; ?>;
        }  
   </style>

<?php

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'woo_wonder_custom_style', 9999 );
```

I have other default stylesheets as well and they are also included in theme using `wp_enqueue_scripts()` only.

```
 function woo_wonder_stylesheets()
 {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'ww_custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/woo-wonder.css' );
 }

 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'woo_wonder_stylesheets', 11 );
```

I want to set priority of my custom style `woo_wonder_custom_style()` to come below default stylesheets `woo_wonder_stylesheets()`

Any help is much appreciated.

This is my first try with wordpress theme development so please excuse me if I am making any silly mistake.

Thanks

Comment: You'd better hook your function to wp_head instead wp_enqueue_scripts. wp_head fires just before the closing </head> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
function woo_wonder_custom_style(){

 $custom_background_color = get_option('ww_background_color');

?>
<style type="text/css">
    body{
         background-color: <?php echo $custom_background_color; ?>;
    }
```

```
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'woo_wonder_custom_style', 9999 );
?>
```

hope this will helps you.